# Android ListView setAdapter(newA) and leave old ones in ListView more the new, it is possible?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a scenario where i list some items, and and the buttom i had a button to insert new item.

When i click i go to another view, and when i fill all editboxs i save it to database, and now i wanna go back to the list to see if the item is in the list.

What i do is figure out if is some item new in database from last id in listview, and it is, but i return the new item as a cursor.

So my problem is:

I have an existing adapter with older items, and i wanna attach the newly adapter (or item), but i wanna use my costum adapter that encapsules the logic of what ids and columns from cursor i wanna bind.. and i wanna just add the items provided from the last cursor to the old one.

How can i do it?

Comment: What kind of adapter do you have?

Comment: My adapter extends from SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: I just wanna add new items, not adding them all (get all from database again)..

Answer (score 0):

u gonna wanna want youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter (Database adapter).. i just wanna attach new result to the old one

Answer (score 0):

How do older items stores in your custom adapter? If they are in e.g. ArrayList you, than can retrieve it, add new items in it and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`